# MassTransit. Consume from queue with delay

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with RabbitMq broker. And I would like to know is it possible to create a particular queue but start consuming messages from it later? f.e. based on some flag's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start the bus once, which creates the topology in RabbitMQ, and then Stop the bus. At a later time you could create it again, and then Start() it.

You can't Start a previously Started and Stopped bus, but you can do the same configuration at the prescribed interval and Start that instance at that time.